# Fetch flash memory content into PC via uBoot

Tags: vxworks, u-boot

I am having customize board (PowerPC) running operating system with VxWorks kernal with uBoot.
some how my file system(tffs) has corrupted and my VxWorks kernal is not able to boot up. it hangs in boot process. but i still can have connection to uBoot shell. if i format the flash memory and program the operating system again, it will start working, but i somehow need to recover the filesystem and hence i need to copy the flash content to my PC, is there any tool available for PC can do that? i mean connect to uBoot and fetch the flash content entirely?
i believe JTAG will be able to do that, but i dont have that. so i need something else to do that for me. 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U-Boot often support `tftp` transfers (provided you have Ethernet) or even XMODEM/kermit transfers over the serial port. Without knowing your exact u-boot, I will point out that there is a built in `help` functionality which will document all of the commands available.

Comment: yes, i have modified version of uBoot, we have our own ethernet based protocol. and board also has ethernet that supports tftp transfer and boot image from PC via TFTP. but tftp is always used from PC to target transfer. neither target to PC. so i m wondering if that's possible